# Update mysql database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Can anybody point out what's wrong with my code? I am trying to update an attribute but I got an error

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for
>   column 'phone' at row 1

Is there anything wrong with the SQL command? Thank you!

```
String queryString = "";
String selectedItem = (String) searchTypeCmb.getSelectedItem();
String searchTerm = searchTermField.getText();
String id = theId.getText();
textArea.setText("");

if ("Phone".equals(selectedItem)) {
    queryString = "UPDATE person SET phone = '" + (searchTerm) + 
        " WHERE driverID = " + (id) + "'";
}
else if ("Address".equals(selectedItem)) {
    queryString = "UPDATE person SET address = '" + (searchTerm) + 
        " WHERE driverID = " + (id) + "'";
}

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dealer", "root", "admin");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate(queryString);
```

Here is my DB schema

```
create table person
( driverID int unsigned not null primary key,
  firstName char(20) not null,
  lastName char(20) not null,
  address char(30) not null,
  phone char(20)
);

create table cars
( license char(10) not null,
  brand char(20) not null,
  model char(20) not null,
  year char(10),
  status char(10) not null,
  carID int unsigned not null primary key
);
```

Comment: What datatype is your `Phone` column?

Comment: Check your size of colom. I think it is less than the data you want to insert

Comment: We need to see the DB schema: its telling you the column type might be too small.

Comment: You are also missing the enclosing quotation mark (`'`), in both cases. Also please consider using prepared statements.

Comment: Just set it to `varchar` and increase the size to what you want to have.

Comment: i just added my DB schema. Thank you guys for helping

Comment: You are trying to update all person table rows with value of '"+searchTerm) +" WHERE driverID = " + (id) + "'". Correct your update sql for phone and address.

Comment: There you have it. Is the string you try to insert longer than 20?

Comment: I don't know why it updates all person's phone in the table. Any idea?

Comment: MadProgrammer is already answered it. Correct your update sql for both of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, your missing closing quotes around your text...

```
"UPDATE person SET phone = '" + (searchTerm) + " WHERE driverID = " + (id) + "'"
                                                ^-----------------------------^
```

Which you probably want to be

```
"UPDATE person SET phone = '" + (searchTerm) + "' WHERE driverID = " + (id)
```

But having said that, I'd strongly encourage you to use `PreparedStatements` instead.

```
String queryString = "";
String selectedItem = (String) searchTypeCmb.getSelectedItem();
String searchTerm = searchTermField.getText();
String id = theId.getText();
textArea.setText("");
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dealer", "root", "admin")) {

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    if ("Phone".equals(selectedItem)) {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE person SET phone = ? WHERE driverID = ?");
    } else if ("Address".equals(selectedItem)) {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE person SET address = ? WHERE driverID = ?");
    }
    if (stmt != null) {
        stmt.setString(1, searchTerm);
        stmt.setString(2, id);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details...

Comment: That makes a nice change

Comment: Like @MadProgrammer said, `PreparedStatements` is the best practice for these kind of queries

Answer (score 0):

If you have the message

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'phone'
```

The data that you are writing in the column "phone" is longer than the maximum length of that field on the database.
So you can:

- Truncate the phone value before inserting it in the database
- Alter your column length in the database